# pagination doesn't work with custom page on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress. the problem is pagination in my custom page doesn't work I searched bunch of answers on google but it couldn't find right answer with my problem. actually it works in Index.php but never works on custom pages. if I click the number 2 of pagination it never go to page 2 and just staying in page 1 and nothing changed than before I clicked next page number. here is my codes with the problem. hope i can fix it thanks for reading! and this is the page i'm making.
http://hongikezer.esy.es/hongik_draw/draw/

first code is functions.php
second one is css file
third code is single-hingik_draw.php which is my custom page

```js
<?php
function register_my_menu() {
 register_nav_menu('header-menu',__('Header Menu'));
}
add_action('init','register_my_menu');

/*Sidebar Enable*/
function register_my_sidebar() {
 register_sidebar(
  array(('name')=>__('Main Sidebar')
  )
 );
}
add_action('init','register_my_sidebar');

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 232, 211);

//custom page
add_action('init', 'codex_custom_init');
function codex_custom_init(){
 // About
 register_post_type(
 'hongik_about', array(
   'labels' => array('name' => __('about'),'singular_name' => __('about1')),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumnail'),   
  )
 );
 // test
 register_post_type(
 'hongik_test', array(
   'labels' => array('name' => __('test'),'singular_name' => __('test')),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumnail'),   
  )
 ); 
 // Curri
 register_post_type(
 'hongik_curri', array(
   'labels' => array('name' => __('curri'),'singular_name' => __('curri')),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumnail'),   
  )
 ); 
 // Drawing
 register_post_type(
 'hongik_draw', array(
   'labels' => array('name' => __('draws'),'singular_name' => __('draw')),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumnail'),   
  )
 );  
 // Blog
 register_post_type(
 'hongik_blog', array(
   'labels' => array('name' => __('blogs'),'singular_name' => __('blog')),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumnail'),   
  )
 );  
 flush_rewrite_rules();
}






//pagination
function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {

 if( is_singular() )
  return;

 global $wp_query;

 /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
 if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
  return;

 $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
 $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

 /** Add current page to the array */
 if ( $paged >= 1 )
  $links[] = $paged;

 /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
 if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
  $links[] = $paged - 1;
  $links[] = $paged - 2;
 }

 if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
  $links[] = $paged + 2;
  $links[] = $paged + 1;
 }

 echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

 /** Previous Post Link */
 if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
  printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

 /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
 if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
  $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

  printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

  if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
   echo '<li>…</li>';
 }

 /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
 sort( $links );
 foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
  $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
  printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
 }

 /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
 if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
  if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
   echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

  $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
  printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
 }

 /** Next Post Link */
 if ( get_next_posts_link() )
  printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

 echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}





?>
```

```css
/* Pagination */
.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.navigation li {
 display: inline;
}

.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
 background-color: #6FB7E9;
 border-radius: 3px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 12px;
 padding: 0.75rem;
}

.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a {
 background-color: #3C8DC5;
}
```

```html
<?php /*Template Name: Drawing*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">


<!--<//?php
if (have_posts()):
 while (have_posts()):the_post();?>
  <div class="test_box">
   <//?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </div>
<//?php
 endwhile;
endif;
?>-->

<!--wp_query-->
<?php
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $args=array(
  'post_type'=>'post',
  'posts_per_page'=>3,
  'paged'=>$paged,
);

 query_posts($args);
   $args = array('cat' => 4);
   $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

   if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
      while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
         $category_posts->the_post();

?>

<div class='test_box'><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>      
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>    
<?php
      endwhile;
   endif; 
?>
<!--//wp_query-->

<!--pagination-->
<?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
<!--//pagination-->
</div>


<!--<//?php get_sidebar();?>-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: So, what is the issue here? I mean in which code? Please make it obvious.

Comment: Hey I found this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129486/using-paged-redirects-page-2-to-page-1 Let me know if it works.

Comment: This was asked many times at [wordpress.se], just research for "pagination" over there to find possible solutions